# Error out when click Google Chat Bot interactive button with NET.CORE

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am creating a bot for the hangout chat via C#, I was able to create simple messages and messages on cards, but I am not able to work with `CARD_CLICKED`.

It displays the message that `could not connect to the bot, try later.`

Retrieving the error message, I noticed this message:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Unsupported path name in update message field mask.
```

How can I get this to work in C#?